# Why was this question on airport fee administration closed as opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

The question [Why is the airport tax at some airport charged outside the airfare ticket but instead must be paid at the airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/153841/1810) was closed as opinion-based. However, none of the close-voters left a comment. Why was this question  closed as opinion-based? It seems ok to me as there could be some simple explanation such as some passengers don't have to pay the airport fee.

Answer (score 1):

Last time you asked this question people were willing to write some possible reasons in comments.
Non of them was sure enough to post as an answer.

This time they remember those comments and that no answer was given, as no one person can be sure why several governments do things.

Comment: "no one person can be sure why several governments do things." -> assuming that it is indeed the government who made the decision, governments often explain their decisions, and often act rationally (why wouldn't they).

Comment: We can speculate as to reasons why it's sometimes done this way, but if the reason is something like "the airport authority wants to collect the money directly without letting the tax agency/central government/regional government take some or all of it for themselves," that's not necessarily going to be explained in such plain terms in a written government document.

Comment: @ZachLipton I disagree, many decisions from governments or other authorities have a reasoning that is well documented.